# JUnitTestLogger.dll is not copied on build when it is a transitive dependency

Tags: .net-core, build, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I'm making a core package for all the test projects in several solutions. A dependency graph is like:

```
MyTests.csproj -> MyTestFramework (nuget package) -> JUnitTestLogger (nuget package)
```

The problem is JUnitTestLogger.dll has to be copied to the output folder on the build of `MyTests.csproj`, or it just doesn't work. OK, I add:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

to `MyTests.csproj` and build again. As a result, there is every transitive dependency dll in the output folder... except for JUnitTestLogger.dll. I've checked its source code [JUnitTestLogger.csproj](https://github.com/syncromatics/JUnitTestLogger/blob/master/src/JunitTestLogger/JUnitTestLogger.csproj) and found nothing special.

What's wrong with this package, why is it not copied? I'm asking here, not on Github because of low activity at the project's repo.

`MyTests.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyTestFramework" Version="1.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`MyTestFramework.csproj` (part):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="JUnitTestLogger" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Auto-generated `MyTestFramework.nuspec` (part):

```
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp2.2">
    <dependency id="JUnitTestLogger" version="1.1.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a maintainer on JunitXml.TestLogger (A newer package than the one you mentioned, but both were forked from the same source in [Github/Spekt](https://github.com/spekt/) and share some code). The main thing I am aware of that is unusual with the test loggers is that they are referenced in your project, but not used by the code.

I haven't seen this specific issue, but there have been several in the past [like this one](https://github.com/spekt/nunit.testlogger/issues/23) where the library isn't copied on build. When I first used these libraries I had to put extra steps in my CI builds to copy the library in. From what I recall, my solution was the same as the one in the issue, which was to switch from `msbuild` to `dotnet build`. So maybe that or one of the other closed issues there will give a clue.

Comment: "Referenced but not used" is not the issue. I've just added a random package from nuget and rebuilt the project with `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` option. The package dll have appeared in the output folder.